# Clicking in selenium python after using move_by_offset()

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to navigate through a miniature window containing a grid (1000+ rows) which lies inside of a website. And my goal requires me to click each row of the grid. Initially I tried locating each row using xPATH but there is no reliable way to do this because when I scroll down the grid, the xPATH changes (eg. row 1  -> ...div/div[1]/..., row n -> ...div/div[6]/...)

therefore to get around this issue, I used actionChains move_by_offset and located the row I want this way. and using a loop to add on some grid-width each time, before hitting some maximum number of rows that can appear on screen and scrolling down using a.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).
This is all working well and i can see the hover animation above the rows when i want them. However, I cannot get the actionChains to click on the rows when hovering. I have tried click, double click and click_and_hold + release to no success.
Any help on either making move_by_offset + click work or using xPATH's more effectively would be great.

For context, I am using this on website for work so I cannot release the URL/photos of it. This is my first time using selenium.

```
for s in range(n):
    
    scrollLim = 7
    base = 180
    
    for x in range(scrollLim):
        print(str(x))
        a.reset_actions()
        a.move_by_offset(60, base + 60 * x).double_click()
        a.perform()
        time.sleep(1)

        if x == scrollLim - 1:
            a.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
```

Comment: do you get error when you try to click? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: better show URL for this page, and maybe create minimal working code so we could simply copy and run to test problem. At this moment we can't see full HTML on this page, we can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question.